# Craft not Downloading Auto Update - HttpException on OS X PHP56

Tags: php, auto-updates

I have a development system running OS X / nginx / php-fpm 5.6 and I've pulled down a version of my site from my git repository. The site is currently running an out of date version of craft, however it appears to have issue connecting to the craft update server when I check for an update, simply saying ‘You’re up to date!' (which it isn't).

This only happens on the testing system so I'm guessing it's a configuration issue in php, but having reconfigured php several times I still have this issue. It also causes plugins like the Directory plugin and DUKT's Videos plugin to return errors like 'Couldn't retrieve account' when querying apis.

Looking at the logs turns up a HttpException, although I'm not entirely sure what would cause this issue? Craft hasn't said anything is wrong with my environment but clearly something is failing somewhere...

```
2014/10/27 23:42:04 [warning] [application] 404 - 
in craft/app/etc/errors/HttpException.php (29)
in craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php (59)
in craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php (293)
2014/10/27 23:42:04 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception     'Craft\HttpException' in craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php:59
```

I installed PHP through homebrew with the command:

```
brew install php56 --with-homebrew-curl --with-homebrew-libxslt --with-homebrew-openssl --without-snmp --without-apache --with-fpm --with-mysql php56
```

Comment: Enable devMode, clear your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` and `cache` folder, reproduce the error, then check the log files for `[error]` or `[warning]` entries. If Craft can't connect to something using cURL, it will cache to not try again for 5 minutes, so keep that in mine while testing. (That's what clearing the cache folder is for).

Comment: I've updated the original post with more info (I was looking in the php logs not the craft log), looks like a HttpException is occouring but still not sure what's causing it.

Comment: That's just a normal 404 being logged. Do you have a `craft/storage/runtime/logs/phperrors.log` file and if so, is anything in it?

Comment: no just a craft.log :/

Comment: Can you zip up your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder and send it to support@buildwithcraft.com? I'll update with an answer here if there is anything relevant.

Comment: yeah can do, the only other thing I'm getting is a     
`2014/10/28 00:07:28 [error] [php] Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (craft/app/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:1392)`

Comment: Oh! 99% of the time that occurs when there is some hidden whitespace character before a `<?php` tag in one of Craft's files.  Check your `craft/config`, public `index.php`, etc.

Comment: I've emailed over a logs.zip, I couldn't see any white space in my files but downloaded a fresh copy of an old version of craft to make sure, still has the error when trying to update to the latest version...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue appears to be with php56: after uninstalling 56 and installing 55 craft works as expected.